# Is a Mann-Whitney U test appropriate here?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I need to run a stats analysis on data at the bottom of this post. Essentially, I want to investigate whether ***Diet Group*** (categorical independent var) or ***# of Stitches*** (categorical independent var) affects ***Score*** (ordinal dependent var).

From what I understand, I would need to use a non-parametric test as my data doesn't seem to be normal / there isn't enough to convince me that I have a normal dataset. This would mean that I can't use a two-way ANOVA (which I was originally recommended) to investigate all three variables together.

From my discussions, I believe I should be conducting two Mann-Whitney U tests (one for ***Diet Group*** vs. ***Score*** and one for ***# of Stitches*** vs. ***Score***. However, as my dependent var (***Score***) essentially falls mostly within two groups (either ***1*** or ***2***) even though the scoring scale itself is 0 - 4, I was informed that these ranked tests wouldn't be ideal as they don't do well when there are lots of ties within the ranking.

**Are there any other statistical tests that I should be using with this non-ideal data set or is Mann-Whitney U the best I'd be able to do?**

**Raw Data:**

| animal | diet group | # stitches | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | ED | 5 | 2 |
| B | ED | 5 | 0 |
| C | ED | 5 | 2 |
| D | ED | 5 | 1 |
| E | ED | 5 | 1 |
| F | ED | 5 | 1 |
| G | ED | 5 | 1 |
| H | ED | 5 | 2 |
| I | ED | 5 | 2 |
| J | WD | 5 | 2 |
| K | WD | 5 | 2 |
| L | WD | 5 | 2 |
| M | WD | 5 | 2 |
| N | WD | 5 | 1 |
| O | ED | 7 | 2 |
| P | WD | 7 | 1 |
| Q | WD | 7 | 2 |
| R | WD | 7 | 2 |
| S | WD | 7 | 2 |
| T | WD | 7 | 2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can correct for ties in the Mann-Whitney test, have you considered using this version? Some software, e.g., Statistica calculate this automatically.

A tie correction method can be found on Wikipedia: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann–Whitney_U_test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test)

Note, that it is still not ideal since your outcome/dependent variable only has three categories.

An alternative could be multinomial logistic regression but your sample size may be too small for this, especially if you originally planned for a t-test in your sample size calculation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).